# How to insert variable into html src?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src

Hello everybody and happy new year !

I try to insert the parameter `$ctrl.configFile.samples` into src but I do something wrong and get an error on the console (like iframe src read `$ctrl.configFile.samples` or something like that):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

function _downloadSamples() {
                    var filePath = path.join(__dirname,'/../','/../config.json');
                    this.configFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8'));
                    $mdDialog.show({
                        controller: sideActionsController,
                        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
                        template:
                        `
                        <md-toolbar class="root-container">   
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="$ctrl.configFile.samples" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
                       `,
                        bindToController: true,
                        clickOutsideToClose: true,
                        fullscreen: true,
                        parent: $rootScope.parentEl
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

JS treats *$ctrl.configFile.samples* as pure string, if you want to get content of that variable you have to write it in this form:

```
src="${ $ctrl.configFile.samples }"
```

With template literals you can access variables like this: `some string... ${variable} ... rest of the string.

Read more about [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: now it throwing console err :$ctrl is not defined.

edited : works ! using this. instead $ctrl.

Comment: @TomCohen You should vote for answer, if you think it's helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use single quotation like this,

`'<md-toolbar class="root-container">

<iframe width="1280" height="720" src=" ' + $ctrl.configFile.samples + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe> '`